# CURL forcing download of webpage in gz format

Tags: php, curl

I am running some PHP code to my browser.

If I navigate to a URL like google.com it tells me the document has moved here . .  i.e to another google link.

I set `cURL` follow location to true.

Also. When the query actually goes through it forces my browser to download a webpage in a **.gz** file.

Please help. I don't want it to download. I want it to display.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, trim("http://".trim($host).$q)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, intval(trim($port)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $v);
```

**EDIT  ::**

**Your browser sent a bad request** when requesting sites like stackoverflow.com. .  even 4shared.com does the same thing.

Here is the `HTTPHEADER` array I use in `cURL`;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Proxy-Connection: Close

    [1] => Cache-Control: max-age=0

    [2] => User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1017.2 Safari/535.19

    [3] => Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

    [4] => Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

    [5] => Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

    [6] => Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

    [7] => Cookie: __qca=P0-9

    [8] => Connection: Close
)
```

It's the same curl code I use above.

```
    Host: stackoverflow.com                                 
    Q: /questions/tagged/java
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For solving the gzip problem: try setting [`CURLOPT_ENCODING`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to an empty string before setting `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`. The problem is that cURL is not expecting a compressed response (since you haven't set what encodings it should accept) but manually ask for a compressed response anyway using your custom HTTP headers.

Comment: WOW! Thanks Sir! It works. But do you know why some site's like stackoverflow say `your browser sent a bad request`?

Comment: @Blank Did this issue only start occuring after you've applied my solution? In that case, cURL might be sending the `Accept-Encoding` header twice now; if you set `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to `true` you can verify whether this is the case. If it is, the most simple solution would be to strip the header from your `HTTPHEADER` array. If it isn't, there's probably some other problem with the headers. You'll need to debug a bit (for example remove them one by one) to see what's causing it.

Comment: No it was before your code. Your code fixed the downloading of webpages in gz format.

Comment: @Blank I can't seem to reproduce your bad request issue... here's my [test case](http://pastebin.com/G8E6JfpW) and the corresponding [output](http://pastebin.com/diRGHPA1), a normal 200 status code followed by the stackoverflow homepage. Could you create a test case that causes the server to send a bad request response?

Comment: I've run into problems. Your browser sent a bad request. Bad request.